# Why doesn't redirection work in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)Itemid=111&(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /d/index.php?%2 [R=301,L]
```

Works great for addresses `/index.php?Itemid=111&board=100.300`

But doesn't work for `/d/index.php?Itemid=111&board=100.300`

That is, if it is in a subdirectory, redirection does not work.

I tried the code for `.htaccess` that I showed above.

**UPDATE:**

In the `/d/` directory there is a `.htaccess` file with the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /d/
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean nothing happens? Or do you get an error or undesirable redirect? Is this rule in the root .htaccess file? Do you have any other .htaccess file(s), perhaps in the `/d` subdirectory? Do you have any other rules in the .htaccess file(s)?

Comment: Please try to add a bit more debugging details to your question (there is an "edit" button below it): what redirection do you see in your browsers networking console? What exactly happens if you make a test request? Do you see anything in your http server's error log file? Are you really sure you test using a fresh anonymous browser window or make a _deep_ reload for the test requests?

Comment: MrWhite, thanks a lot for the tip! 

In the /d/ directory there was a .htaccess file with the code: 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /d/ 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [R=301,L] 

I removed this and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MrWhite, thanks a lot for the tip! In the `/d/` directory there was a `.htaccess` file with the code: `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteBase /d/` `RewriteRule ^$ index.php [R=301,L]` I removed this and now it works.

Yes, that would have certainly caused the problem since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. The mod_rewrite directives in the child config (`/d/.htaccess`) would have completely overridden the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file in the root. The mod_rewrite directives in the root would not even have been processed.

It would seem these directives in `/d/.htaccess` are superfluous anyway so should be removed to resolve this issue.

mod_rewrite inheritance and how the mod_rewrite directives are *merged* between parent/child configs can be controlled with the [`RewriteOptions` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions).